# How to find reflection matrix in PCA?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations, svd, reflection

I have bunch of 3d objects of different shapes (point clouds) and I am finding their principal components (three orthogonal vectors) using PCA. When I am checking the determinant of PC vectors then 60% objects shows +1 and 40% objects shows -1. 
That means 40% objects are get reflected in either X, Y or Z or any combination. 
How should I find the reflection matrix so that determinate of all objects should be +1.

Comment: Please clarify what "60% objects shows +1 and 40% objects shows -1" means.

Comment: Suppose I have 1000 point cloud objects of various shapes and if I calculate the determinant of PC vectors of an individual object then I am getting determinate value +1 for at least 600 objects.

Comment: and remaining 400 objects shows -1

Comment: I still have no idea what you're talking about. Please translate that to mathematical language. Easier to reason about points, lines, planes and the like rather than "objects".